# Rails - why does `accepts_nested_attributes_for` set `autosave` to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, if you declare [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your model, `autosave` is set to true for the child association. Is this necessary?

According to my understanding, Rails will already validate all new and changed children without declaring `autosave: true`. It seems that would cover all cases where you are accepting nested attributes for the child association. However, with `autosave: true` the child now gets validated  every time the parent is saved, **even if the child is unchanged**.

This can have major unintended consequences, especially if, for instance, you modify the child model in such a way that a large amount of your records are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `validate: false` on the association. You can see from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html that activating `autosave` (through `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in our case) always validates the record unless you use `validate: false`

Answer (score 0):

Good question!  I just ran into this surprise myself.

I think Rails will only save/validate *new* child records when autosave is nil (the default).

In `save_belongs_to_association(reflection)`, it looks like it only saves the associated record if it **is a *new* record or `autosave` is enabled**.

```
      saved = record.save(:validate => !autosave) if record.new_record? || (autosave && record.changed_for_autosave?)
```

I've always found the autosave option to be slightly confusing/inconsistent... But now we're probably stuck with it for backwards compatibility reasons...